# Can I assume that nobody is 65534?

Tags: posix, user-permissions, uid

I'm writing a setuid root program. This program needs to open a file for writing and then write some content. It needs euid 0 only for opening the file, then it can drop privileges.

To drop privileges, I could seteuid to the current uid. But I was thinking at switching to nobody:nogroup.

Now, I was wondering: can I assume that nobody is 65534 on every system (and nogroup is 65534 too)? Is it defined by some standard (POSIX, maybe)?

Comment: It is indeed 65534 on my FreeBSD and Gentoo machines, but on my Arch Linux machine the uid for nobody is 99. So I would say that it's definitely not an assumption you can make in the real world.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. [`nobody` has had at least a few different IDs across distros and time:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier#Special_values)

> Historically, the user “nobody” was assigned UID -2 by several
> operating systems, although other values such as 2^(15)−1 = 32,767 are
> also in use, such as by OpenBSD. For compatibility between 16-bit
> and 32-bit UIDs, many Linux distributions now set it to be 2^(16)−2 =
> 65,534; the Linux kernel defaults to returning this value when a
> 32-bit UID does not fit into the return value of the 16-bit system
> calls. An alternative convention assigns the last UID of the range
> statically allocated for system use (0-99) to nobody: 99.

---

You can however rely on the name (i.e. assume that `nobody` is called "`nobody`" everywhere it exists): [this account is in the Linux Standard Base standard](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/usernames.html) which is supported by all main distributions. So you can use things like `getpwnam("nobody")` (which is the way recommended by the LSB on the link above).

Comment: Can I use getpwnam("nobody")? I mean: is nobody called "nobody" everywhere?

Comment: @Likk [It's in the LSB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186568/what-is-nobody-user-and-group) and there's no way to find an account other than by UID or name -- so I would say yes. Note however that the recommended security setup is now to have a separate user account for each daemon rather that using `nobody`.

Comment: This is very inconvenient. I think the solution is to keep googling until I find an answer that says 'yes you can'.

Comment: @ChrisRobinson "Blessed is he who believes" :-) (S. Griboedov "Woe from Wit")

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Well, exactly. "And warmth to him in the world." I'll take that as the necessary benediction of 65534. But thank you for the arcane background.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the value of `/proc/sys/fs/overflowuid`.

I'm not sure whether it's the same as UID of "nobody". But it should meet your needs.